# Aligning the number of the subfloats

Tags: subfloats

I am writing in the [OSA universal templates](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universal-manuscript-template-for-optica-publishing-group-journals/cschcggvfwrn). Unfortunately the name of the figures is not adjusted. I checked the other questions but they were not helpful. I really appreciate any help. I attached the latex file and a picture of my problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{optica-article}
\journal{oe}
\articletype{Research Article}
\pdfminorversion=7
% Note that article type is not required for Express journals (OE, BOE, OME and OPTCON)
\usepackage{adjustbox}%,makecell
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[caption=false, justification=centerlast]{subfig}
%\usepackage{tabularray}
%\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\setlength{\parindent}{8pt} 
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\cotinv}{cot\,inverse}
\newcommand{\acot}{\cot^{-1}}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\amscases\cases

\begin{document}

\title{ooooo}
%\bigskip
    \author{sara,\authormark{1,*}}

\address{\authormark{1}Department\\}

\email{\authormark{*}sara@gmail} %% email address is required
%\medskip
\begin{abstract} 
    Thhhhhhhhhhhh
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}hhhhhhhhh

\begin{figure*}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.25\textwidth}
    \subfloat[\label{subfig2as}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[\label{subfig2bs}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[\label{subfig2cs}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[\label{subfig2ds}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{fffffffffff} 
    \label{lockingrange}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [caption=false]?

Comment: @JohnKormylo,I do not why!! I just downloaded it from overleaf. Thanks for your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example based on `\subcaptionbox` from [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Sub 1\label{fig:subcaption1}}[0.25\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Sub 2\label{fig:subcaption2}}[0.25\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Sub 3\label{fig:subcaption3}}[0.25\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \subcaptionbox{Sub 4\label{fig:subcaption4}}[0.25\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%
  \caption{The main caption}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can arrange images manually in `minipage`s and wrap everything by `subcaptionblock` to turn each `\caption` inside into a sub-caption.

In the code below, I also applied `\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth}`, which automatically insert its options, here `width`, to each `\includegraphics` to avoid repetitions. It requires to load `adjustbox` with `[Export]` option).

The snippet of the alternative approach

```latex
\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth}     % Requires: \usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
  \begin{subcaptionblock}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{example-image}
      \caption{Sub 1}
      \label{fig:subcaption1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{example-image}
      \caption{Sub 2}
      \label{fig:subcaption2}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{example-image}
      \caption{Sub 3}
      \label{fig:subcaption3}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth}
      \includegraphics{example-image}
      \caption{Sub 4}
      \label{fig:subcaption4}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{subcaptionblock}
  \caption{Another main caption}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your response.  I check it. Although I do not know why this happened. This is the first time.

Comment: your suggestion is very helpful, but I have a problem. The size of the graphs is smaller relative to the past.  If I change the size of the adjustbox or figure, my figure goes to the next line. and this limited me due to length constraints, however, as you determined, the size of the adjustbox is smaller than the linewidth(despite what really is determined)

Comment: I corrected the code. LaTeX adds space after a single line break unless you end the line with `%`. So images would no longer fit the page-width because of those extra 3 spaces. Things should work now.

Comment: Thanks. It works

Answer (score 3):

Package `subcaption` from version 1.3 onwards `\subfloat` environment known from `subfig` package too. If `Gin` keys are employed, your problem can be solved with the following concise code too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
     \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.25\textwidth}
\subfloat[Sub 1 \label{fig:subcaption1}]{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
\subfloat[Sub 2 \label{fig:subcaption2}]{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
\subfloat[Sub 3 \label{fig:subcaption3}]{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
\subfloat[Sub 4 \label{fig:subcaption4}]{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \caption{The main caption}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. It solved my problem.

Comment: +1 for the compact code :) and for demonstrating global settings straight from `graphicx`, which I thought I needed an extra package for.